# How to change bluetooth baud rate in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I need to receive data sent from a hardware device to my android phone via Bluetooth. But I don't receive the exact data. There are some missing samples.
Is it possible to change the baud rate of my bluetooth device on android?
Also, can anyone tell me how to find the default baud rate of my android bluetooth?

Comment: look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576237/android-bluetooth-serial-rfcomm-spp-how-to-change-the-baud-rate)