# Is there a way to change bluetooth module's baud rate via Bluetooth connection with Android device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, spp

I would like to change a default baud rate of the bluetooth module.

I am having an IR receiver which works on baud rate 2400 and it is connected directly to bluetooth module. I want the flow to be IR receiver->Bluetooth module->Android device.

To do that, I assume I need to have the  same baud rate at the Bluetooth module. Is there a way to do it in Android program? To set the baud rate? Or should it be done differently?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576237/android-bluetooth-serial-rfcomm-spp-how-to-change-the-baud-rate) hasn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a specific module, I can only provide a response regarding modules in general. Most modules have an embedded command language for configurations and operations. Most likely, your module will have a command to change the baud rate. Some but not all, modules provide a method for receiving these commands using the wireless SPP profile link. The KC-2114 Bluetooth module by KC Wirefree does provide access for all configuration and operation commands via the wireless link, and can be reconfigured by the Android device.