# Bluetooth serial communication, HC-06 module to Android mobile

Tags: android, c++, c, bluetooth, arduino

I want to transfer data from an Arduino to an android mobile phone. Data will be integers which are continuously generated values from a sensor attached to Arduino . What is the most fastest approach for this ? I mean what is the best code to transfer this data without any delay? I would like to use most optimized code because in my project delays will cause errors in my android app.Please help me. Data rate will be about 1 integer per milisecond .Thanks in advance....

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576237/android-bluetooth-serial-rfcomm-spp-how-to-change-the-baud-rate) you can find information about setting baud rate for android bluetooth serial connection higher than 9600 bit/sec is impossible. You need 16 bit / 0.001 s = 16000 bit/s. So, mission is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to create a connection to, and receive data from, a bluetooth stick reader (cattle ear tags) using the tutorial from the following Google Developers guide. Seems to me that it will keep listening full time for the messages.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

It worked on >= Android 4.3, because only after this version Android is capable of receiving Low Energy Bluetooth.

Comment: I also did a project involving HC-06 and android before. If was a remote controlled robot car. But this is different. I want highest performance. But anyway thankyou very much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

well that gives me an idea, @nopasara 's comment. If I can find a way to include 2 integers per 16bits i will be able to achieve the challenge ? I think that will be a possible task with C language bit operators.....