# Bluetooth receive data from HC05 desn't work. I receive this garbage data ����

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Can someone explain to me what is wrong with the following code? I tried all: adding limit `\n\r` to wait for the end of the line and several other ways. I receive the garbage data always. So I went back to my start code.

Some people told me that it may be the `InputStream` which doesn't receive data, but this does not give me a solution.

```
 private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final InputStream mmInStream;

    // Creation of the connect thread
    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        InputStream tmpIn = null;

        try {
            // Create I/O streams for connection
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // I tried all 128, 8, 256
        int bytes;
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (mmInStream.available()>0){
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);//read bytes from input buffer
                    bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
                }
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}


private void setw() throws IOException {

    blue_tv = findViewById(R.id.blue_tv);
    blue_tv2 = findViewById(R.id.blue_tv2);
    bluetoothConnectDevice();
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(bluetoothSocket);
    mConnectedThread.start();
}

private void bluetoothConnectDevice() throws IOException {

    try {
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        blue_address = bluetoothAdapter.getAddress();
        pairedDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevice.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevice) {
                blue_address = bt.getAddress();
                blue_name = bt.getName();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cane connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                blue_status = "La canne est connectée !";

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); //get mobile bluetooth device
    BluetoothDevice bd = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(blue_address);//connect to the device
    bluetoothSocket = bd.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID); //create a RFCOM (SPP) connexion
    bluetoothSocket.connect();
    try {
        blue_tv.setText("Bluetooth Name : " + blue_name + "\nBluetooth Adress : " + blue_address);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_traject);
    mySR = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    autoCompleteTextView = findViewById(R.id.actv);

    try {
         setw();
    }catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

    blue_status = "La canne n'est pas connectée.";

    bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == handlerState) {
                byte[] readBuff = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String readMessage = new String(readBuff,0,msg.arg1);
                blue_tv2.setText("Data Received = " + readMessage+"\n"+"Data Length = "+readMessage.length());

            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong here. I think you are getting valid data from HC05. However, some characters cannot be printed as the Bluetooth is sending you the data as bytes and every byte cannot be converted into a valid character while you are trying to set them as a text inside a `TextView`.

I would like to suggest you process the `InputStream` first before having it placed in a `TextView`. For example, read the bytes received first in a byte array and then create a String by yourself like the following.

```
public String toString() {
    String print = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) print += " " + buffer[i];
    return "Buffer (size=" + buffer.length + " content:" + print;
}
```